# Question about integral/ integration variable / change

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Recently I had to deal with integrals where the integration variable was a multiplication of variables e.g. $d(xy)$ and in the examples that I solved I have come across the following property

$\int f(x) d(xy) = \int y f(x) dx$

so when the integrand was not dependent on one of the factors of the integration variable I could theoretically "pull it out" from the integration variable and write it in the integrand.
Of course I rigorously solved via substitution but the result always would have been the same with the method described above.

I wanted to ask whether this is something which holds in general and whether this property has a name.

Comment: @Gordon, yes of course I could pull $y$ further out of the integral after this step $\int yf(x) dx$, it was just trivial for me that this would follow next, therefore I didn‘t weite it out further

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is nothing else than a change of variable. It is more obvious when considering the reverse direction : set $t := xy$ in $\int yf(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$, so that you obtain $\int f(t/y) \,\mathrm{d}t$. Then, the expression $\int f(x) \,\mathrm{d}(xy)$ corresponds to an intermediate step, where the old variable $x$ hasn't been replaced by the new variable $t$ inside the integrand yet.